# Delphi XE4 iOS open email program not working

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-xe4

I am testing the following code on an iPhone4 (without sim card, but I don't see how that can matter since its mail program is otherwise working fine):

The **SharedApplication** and **canOpenURL** etc. are all routines provided by XE4.

```
procedure TFormMain.sbContactsDetailsEmailClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  S: string;
  NSU: NSUrl;
begin
 // URL.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
  S := 'mailto:' + 'info@example.com' + '?subject=' + 'title' + '&body=';
  NSU := StringToNSUrl(S);
  if SharedApplication.canOpenURL(NSU) then
    SharedApplication.openUrl(NSU)
  ;
end;
```

Unfortunately, it seems **SharedApplication.canOpenURL(NSU)** returns false. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: The doco says that openUrl confirms "_another_ application will be launched to handle it" (the URL).  If you enter your URL into a browser does it open an email client for example?  Is an application associated with mailto?

Comment: @Jason Just tested what you said, and yes, email program does pop up if I enter mailto:info@example.com into browser. (I also tested it with a subject added)

Comment: Anyone feel free to make an answer, and I will award bounty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should have through of it myself, but here goes:

do work

```
'mailto:info@example.com?subject=test'
'mailto:info@example.com?subject=test%20test'
```

does not work

```
'mailto:info@example.com?subject=test test'
```

(i.e. solution is to convert spaces to %20)

Comment: So you've just had to [`URL encode`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) that string.

Comment: Yep. Upvoted your comment since I should have included that info in my answer.